# understanding how laravel interprets blade form url?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have the below form in a larvel view:

```
<div id="admin">

    <h1>Products Admin Panel</h1><hr>

    <p>Here you can view, delete, and create new products.</p>

    <h2>Products</h2><hr>
    <!--admin/fileupload/create-->
    {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/products/create' , 'files'=>true)) }}
    <p>
        {{ Form::file('image') }}
    </p>
    {{ Form::submit('Create Product' , array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}

</div>  <!-- end admin -->
```

I am new to laravel and basically just want to understand , in the URL when i specify `'url'=>'admin/products/create'` , what is laravel going to look for ? 
a `modal` called products ? or a `controller` called products ? and a method `getCreate` or `postCreate` inside it ? what is `admin` then , i want to understand how laravel interprets this blade form url , can anybody explain ?

I want somebody to explain to me how does laravel interpret blade form url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel,you will specify which url to be processed by which controller and by which method inside that controller.This specify must be do in routes.php file that is located in `projectname/app/Http/routes.php .`

When you specify the `'url'=>'admin/products/create'` you must define the `route in routes.php .`

Route can be define in different ways like:

```
Route::get('admin/products/create','ProductController@crete');
```

Here you can use `get` or `post` according to your request.

Another way you can do is

```
Route::get('admin/products/create',array(
      'as'=> 'create-product',
      'uses'=>'ProductController@create'
));
```

Now , you can do like this `route('create-product');` instead of `'url'=>'admin/products/create'` .

Another way by using Route group

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin'],function(){
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'products'],function(){
        Route::get('/create',array(
            'as'=>'create-product',
            'uses'=> 'ProductController@create'
        ));

      // Here you can define other route that have the url like /admin/products/*
    });

});
```

Now you can do like `route('create-product')` or `'url'=>'admin/products/create'` Advantage

For more info check the documentation [Here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing)